# How do i stop user going to next page if text box has numbers?

Tags: vb.net

Hi Guys and Girls of the StackOverflow community

I have a little problem I have a text box that if it has numbers in I want them to not be able to proceed to the next form I have tried IsNumeric but only works if the string is all numbers as soon as I enter a letter it allows the user to go to the next page. Here is what I have so far.

```
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("No Numbers in your name!")
    Else
        Me.Hide()
        frmQuestion1.Show()
    End If
```

So does anyone know a way to make it so if any numbers are in string even with some letters in there it wont go to next form.

Comment: run a regex, iterate over each character, etc.  There's a number of possibilities.  Regex is the best way most likely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic regular expression validation.
try this:

```
Dim re as RegEx = new RegEx("\d")
If re.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text) Then
    MessageBox.Show("No Numbers in your name!")
Else
    Me.Hide()
    frmQuestion1.Show()
End If
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the fast reply! I got it working with this :D tho for some reason i had to change RegEx to "System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex" apart from that it worked great. Are you able to tell me what the Regex does im sorta new to this.

Comment: You can start by reading about regular expressions here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx
and reading about the RegEx class here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx